# How to replace all string values from a column to another value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace

I want to replace all values from a column, like for example, to replace all values from `lane` column to 'All lanes' value. I tried to use REPLACE function : `REPLACE(lane, '%', 'All lanes')`  but it does not work that way though. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

| lane |
| --- |
| WA-OR |
| TX-NY |
| MA-NJ |

Expected output:

| lane |
| --- |
| All lanes |
| All lanes |
| All lanes |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `update`:

```
update t
    set lane = 'All lanes';
```

Note this permanently affects all rows.  If you just want the result in a query:

```
select 'All lanes' as lane
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks! Are there any ways that we could use REPLACE in this case?

Comment: `REPLACE()` would not be appropriate for what you want to accomplish.